# programming tests/questions

Tags: c++

Does anybody know a good reference I can use to prepare for interview questions/tests about c++ programming? From basic questions about OO programming to advanced ones.

Thank you,

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25836/what-is-the-best-c-interview-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out C++ -FAQ lite by Marshall Cline. It covers almost everything that  might be asked in a C++ technical interview

Comment: +1. This is good suggestion. FREE resource!

Answer (score 1):

Check out "[Programming Interview Exposed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047012167X)".

Answer (score 0):

Ask stack overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447/favorite-c-interview-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817020/interview-questions-for-junior-c-and-c-developer-position